# NBF image in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, backup, disk-image

I have a .nbf disk image created by acer backup manager of a windows laptop. How can I boot this system from a linux host system with virtualbox?

Comment: Are you sure it's a bootable disk image? Open it using [7Zip](http://7-zip.org). Does it look like a disk image?

Comment: I don't know how to extract it. I tried to find out the compression used by using the file command, but it just reports that it is a data file.

Comment: Install 7-zip, then right click on your file -> 7-zip menu -> Open Archive; Or open 7-zip, navigate to and select your file, press right click -> Open Inside. 7-zip supports all common disk image files, so if it can't open file then its not a normal bootable image. Try it. But I think VirtualBox will not be able to boot from it, until it's a variety of VHD/HDD/VDI/VMDK file.